# Show that $E(\mathrm{var}(Y|X)) \leq (1 - \mathrm{corr}(X,Y)^2) \mathrm{var}(Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, correlation, variance

> Expectation of conditional variance (Exercise 4.6.7 from Grimmett and Stirzaker): Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with correlation $\rho$. Show that $E(\mathrm{var}(Y|X)) \leq (1 - \rho^2) \mathrm{var}(Y)$.

This is how far I got:

By definition,

$$
\mathrm{var}(Y|X) = E(Y^2|X) - E(Y|X)^2.
$$

Taking expectations of both sides gives

\begin{align}
E(\mathrm{var}(Y|X)) &= E(E(Y^2|X)) - E(E(Y|X)^2), \\
&= E(Y^2) - E(E(Y|X)^2).
\end{align}

And from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
\begin{align}
E(XY)^2 &= E(X E(Y|X))^2 \\
&\leq E(X^2)E(E(Y|X)^2), \\
\implies E(E(Y|X)^2) &\geq \frac{E(XY)^2}{E(X^2)}.
\end{align}

So therefore,
$$
E(\mathrm{var}(Y|X)) \leq E(Y^2) - \frac{E(XY)^2}{E(X^2)}.
$$

How can I proceed from here? I tried expanding $(1 - \rho^2) \mathrm{var}(Y)$ after substituting
$$
\rho^2 = \frac{(E(XY) - E(X)E(Y))^2}{(E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2)(E(X^2) - E(X)^2)}
$$
but couldn't get the right hand side to match the left hand side.

Comment: Assume wlog that $E(X)=E(Y)=0$ then use the identity $E(XY)^2=\rho^2E(X^2)E(Y^2)$.

Comment: Can you explain why it is okay to make the assumption that $E(X) = E(Y) = 0$? Wouldn't $\rho$ change if the means are shifted to 0?

Comment: Because $E(\mathrm{var}(Y|X))=E(\mathrm{var}(\bar Y|\bar X))$, $\rho=\mathrm{cov}(\bar X,\bar Y)$ and $\mathrm{var}(Y)=\mathrm{var}(\bar Y)$, where $\bar X=X-E(X)$ and $\bar Y=Y-E(Y)$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.